# visjs first group/last group line change the height when an entry is added

Tags: vis.js

I don't know if there is some calculation or something like that, but the first / last line (depending on the orientation setting) when groups are used becomes higher when an entry is added.
First group (line) is higher

[image]

When an entry is in other line, the height is as it should be

[image]

is this known ? why it happens ?

thanks a lot for any help

regards
Marek

Answer (score 1):

thanks to Jos de Jong personally, I got a solution. It's answered here:
https://github.com/almende/vis/issues/1388

Jos, thanks! ;)